# Compact Framework 2.0 for Mobile Device (Handheld)

Tags: visual-studio-2008, compact-framework, cab

I am trying to put an application developed in VB in VisualStudio 2008 on a Juniper Allegro2 device...

The problem is that nn my desktop I have Compact Framework 2.0 v2.0.50727 and I cannot find a .CAB file to install the 50727 version on the Handheld device.

Someone know where I can find this specific version to install on the Device ?

Answer (score 1):

Is this running "Microsoft® Windows Embedded Handheld 6.5.3"? Then use "\Windows\cgacutil.exe" on the device to get the installed .Net Framework Version.

The MS .Net Compact Framework distribution cab files are located on the PC at below "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft.NET\SDK\CompactFramework". For example: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft.NET\SDK\CompactFramework\v2.0\WindowsCE\wce500\armv4i\NETCFv2.wm.armv4i.cab"

There is normally no need to install an 'older' or the 'same' framework on the device. Normally WEH653 comes with CF3.5 installed.

Update:
NETCF 2 SP2 redistributable (does not say exact CF version)
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17981

But this site says CF2 SP2 is 2.0.6129.0: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Compact_Framework
(see also history at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228799%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Where do you get this info: 2.0.50727?

BTW: In most cases (99.9%) using a newer runtime version is no problem. Even running CF2 apps with a CF3.5 runtime

Another point is, that if you enable project properties "Distribute latest Runtime" (or similar), VS will deploay a CF runtime cab to the device before it launches the project's application.

Some projects set specific version numbers for assemblies. Please check this and possibly remove the explicit version request.

Comment: Yes, I already did this.

Allegro2 (JuniperSys) uses CF2.0 not 3.5 according to manufacturer informations I have in hand...

The problem is on VS2008, it uses 2.0.50727 and on /cgacutil, or gives 2.0.5238 and app wont run...

I'm stuck with this... the only way I expect it to run smooth, is to install 2.0.50727 with a .CAB file... file I cannot find to this specific version...

Comment: "according to manufacturer informations I have in hand" instead use cgacutil.exe on the device to get the real information!

Comment: This site says the Allegro has CF3.5! : http://www.junipersys.com/Juniper-Systems-Rugged-Handheld-Computers/support/Downloads/TK6000-Ultra-Rugged-Field-PC/Microsoft-.NET-Compact-Framework